# Is local vector bundle chart a homeomorphism, diffeomorphism, or bijection?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-bundles

I've seen a few definitions, and each demands a local vector bundle chart map $\varphi:\pi^{-1}(U) \to U \times F$ to be something different: homeomorphism, diffeomorphism, or bijection.

E.g.:

1. Wiki, the topology of fiber bundles Lecture notes Ralph L. Cohen - homeomorphism;
2. Notes on Vector Bundles Aleksey Zinger - diffeomorphism;
3. Foundations of mechanics 2nd edition R. Abraham and E. Marsden - bijection, but put additional constraint onto transition maps to be a diffeomorphisms.

I believe, there is a meaningful answer for such illusional ambiguity as it is for manifolds: see [Verifying that a space is a Manifold via compatible charts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4710773/verifying-that-a-space-is-a-manifold-via-compatible-charts)

Comment: In the definition of a continuous vector bundle, the map $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism. In the definition of a smooth vector bundle, the map $\varphi$ is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, am I right supposing that the transition map of a continuous vector bundle isn't supposed to be a diffeomorphism?

Comment: The transition maps of a continuous vector bundle will be homeomorphisms.

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept of "vector bundle" has a topological variant and a smooth variant. It always depends on the context whether we work with topological or smooth vector bundles.

1. Topological vector bundles.

Here we have a continuous map $p : E \to B$ between topological spaces $E, B$ and require the existence of local vector bundle charts $\varphi:\pi^{-1}(U) \to U \times F$ which are *homeomorphisms*. "Homeomorphism" is the maximum we can expect because there are no structures on $E, B$ beyond their topologies.

2. Smooth vector bundles.

Here we have a smooth map $p : E \to B$ between smooth manifolds $E, B$ and require the existence of local vector bundle charts $\varphi:\pi^{-1}(U) \to U \times F$ which are *diffeomorphisms*. The smooth structures of $E, B$ allow the stronger "diffeomorphism" requirement. Clearly each smooth vector bundle is a topological vector bundle. But there are topological vector bundles $p : E \to B$ with smooth manifolds $E, B$ which are no smooth vector bundles.

What is difference between the above concept of *smooth vectoer bundle* and  Abraham and Marsden's approaach in "Foundations of Mechanics"?

They do not start with a smooth map $p : E \to B$, but with a **set** $S$ which has a *vector bundle atlas* $\mathscr B$ consisting of *local bundle charts on $S$*. Since $S$ does not yet have a topology, such bundle charts can only be required to be *bijections*. However, in a vector bundle atlas *the transition maps are required to be diffeomorphisms*. This can be done because the transition functions are maps between open subsets of Euclidean spaces.

This allows to give $S$ a unique topology making all local bundle charts in $\mathscr B$ homeomorphisms. Doing so makes $\mathscr B$ a smooth atlas on $S$. Thus $S$ receives the structure of a smooth manifold denoted by $E$. This procedure is discussed in [Verifying that a space is a Manifold via compatible charts](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4710773).

There is still no map $p : E  \to B$ to a smooth manifold $B$, but the authors introduce the zero-section $E_0 \subset E$ which is a smooth submanifold of $E$ and a map $\pi : E \to E_0$ which is smooth. It is then easy to see that $\pi : E \to E_0$ is a smooth vector bundle in the sense of the above definition.

We can therefore say that Abraham and Marsden have chosen a *constructive approach*: They build smooth vector bundles by smoothly patching together local vector bundles of the form $U \times F$. Their approach results in the same concept of a vector bundle as in the above definition. For practical purposes this constructive approach is in some sense superior. Many standard smooth vector bundles (as the tangent bundle $TM$ of a smooth manifold $M$) arise by first defining its underlying set which is given the structure of a smooth vector bundle using a vector bundle atlas in the above sense.

Comment: I will copy a part of your answer to the other question I asked before, It perfectly explains definitions divergence of Foundation of Mechanics. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4744988/foundation-of-mechanics-2nd-edition-and-vector-bundle-definitions

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggest there are continuous and smooth vector bundles: smooth requires local bundle chart to be a diffeomorphism as well as transition map, so the vector spaces $F$ attached to each point varies smoothly.
Meanwhile continuous or just vector bundles require both these categories to be homeomorphism.

There are some particularities of definitions in Foundations of mechanics: the author weakened the definition of vector bundle chart to be only a homeomorphism, but requires the transition map to be a diffeomorphism. It's still not clear for me for what