# Difference between "Differentiable Structure" and "Differentiable manifold"

Tags: differential-geometry

> Let $A^k (M)$ denote the set of all $\mathbb{R}^n$ atlases of clsas $C^k$ on $M$. Two atlases $\mathcal{A}_1$ and $\mathcal{A}_2$ in $A^k (M)$ are said to be equivalent if $\mathcal{A}_1 \cup \mathcal{A}_2$ is also in $A^k (M)$.\...
> The relation introduced is an equivalence relation in $A^k (M)$ and hence partitions $A^k (M)$ into disjoint equivalent classes. Each of these equivalence classes is called a differentiable structure of class $C^k$ on $M$. \
> A set $M$ together with a differentiable structure of class $C^k$ is called a differentiable $n$-manifold of class $C^k$ or simply a $C^k$-manifold.

(An Introduction to Differential Geometry, K.S.Amur et al.)

I don't quite get what the difference of differentiable structure and manifold. It seems to me that equivalence classes is an equivalence class on the above equiv. relation, and manifold is just equiv. class with specifying $M$, but haven't $M$ already specified into the differentiable structure?

Comment: A differentiable manifold is a topological manifold that admits a differentiable structure, i.e a $\mathscr C^1$-atlas

Comment: The differentiable structure is what we place on top of a set in order to view it as a differentiable manifold. Yes, the underlying set needs to be fixed in order to define the differentiable structure, so we cannot talk about a differentiable structure totally in isolation of the underlying set, but having nomenclature like this allows us to talk about a single set $M$ with two different differentiable structures attached to it (to make two different manifolds).

Comment: As an analogue, recall elementary linear algebra. We could take the set $\Bbb{C}$ and equip it with different vector space structures! We could look at standard addition/scalar multiplication over $\Bbb{C}$, and it is one-dimensional. Or, we could look at it over $\Bbb{R}$, and it's two dimensional (i.e. a totally different vector space). Over $\Bbb{Q}$, it's infinite-dimensional! These are three different vector spaces, over the same set, differing only in the "vector space structures" we impose onto the same set $\Bbb{C}$.

Comment: @Zest
If I understand correctly, can I say something like $(X, \mathcal{J})$ is a topological space and $\mathcal{J}$ is a topology (from topological space). Similarly, for $\cup_{i \in I} U_i = M$ , $\{(U_i, \phi_i): i \in I\}$ is a differentiable manifold and $M$ is manifold (from differentiable structure)?

Comment: "Two atlases $\mathcal{A}_1$ and $\mathcal{A}_2$ in $A^k (M)$ are said to be equivalent if $\mathcal{A}_1$ and $\mathcal{A}_2$ are in $A^k (M)$" - this does not make sense. Do you mean  $\mathcal{A}_1 \cup \mathcal{A}_2$ ?

Comment: @Paul Frost Yes, you are correct. Sorry for typo.

Comment: Now edit again and correct more typos....

Comment: You should also explain whether the authors define the concept of a $C^k$ atlas for a set $M$ or for a toplogioal space $M$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4710773 for both points of view.